# AJAX WebMethod help

Tags: .net, jquery, pagemethods

I have been trying to access a .NET WebMethod from jQuery AJAX but I cannot get it to work.  I have read everything I can find on SO and other sites and nothing seems to be working.

My C# code is such

```
[WebMethod]
public static string TestAjax()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

and the JavaScript code is

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ManageEvent.aspx/TestAjax",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg)
    {
        alert(msg.d);
    },
    error: function(result)
    {
        alert("error: " + result.status);
    }
});
```

The end goal was to do a form submission to the database using AJAX without reloading the entire page but at the moment I can't even get it to return back a String.  When I click the input button to which this code is attached the error code is called giving a status of 12030.  But when I test the code outside of Visual Studio I still error but with a status of 200.  Is there anything blatantly obvious in my code that would cause this error?

Thanks a ton

EDIT:

I have gotten the WebMethod to work using ASP.NET Ajax's ScriptManager by installing [ASP.NET AJAX 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en) and calling in my Javascript

```
PageMethods.TextAjax(OnSuccess, OnFail);
```

where OnSuccess and OnFail are functions.  However I still cannot get jQuery's AJAX to work.  It still throws the 12030 error status.

Comment: can you show your web.config? you might be missing values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web service was missing a [ScriptService] tag which fixed it after installing ASP.NET AJAX

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything wrong with your code. Install [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) and see where's the problem with your setup. Here's a full working example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Services" %>

<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    [WebMethod]
    public static string TestAjax()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/TestAjax",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("error: " + result.status);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when I run this in VS I get the "error: 12030" just like before.  This is leading me to believe it might be a configuration issue.  Is there something special I need to do in the web.config to get this type of Ajax to work?  I have Ajax working elsewhere in the form of ashx handlers but the functionality I'm going for here would be better in the Page Methods.

Comment: Using the JS Console in Chrome I noticed that if I remove the json contentType and dataType, the response is the entire Default.aspx page, not the page I am calling the JS from.

Answer (score 0):

That all looks correct.  Does your class look like this:

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
[WebMethod]
public static string TestAjax()
{
    return "Hello World";
}

}
```

Comment: more or less, the header is "public partial class ManageEvent : System.Web.UI.Page"

Comment: I would look elsewhere then.  Have you gotten anything to work yet?

Comment: Not yet.  Even when I step through using the debugger, I put a breakpoint on the C# method and it never seems to reach that.

Comment: Might be a server config problem then.  I wouldn't be able to help you much there...